# Why is this task await leaving the UI context in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, async-await

The following has somewhat shaken my async/await-based belief system.  Under Xamarin/iOS the following fails, saying that UI-related things are being done in a non-UI thread.  Adding check points shows that the context does in fact switch after the async file write.

My understanding is that lacking a ConfigureAwait, the following should be completely safe.  I'm assuming this is a Xamarin nuance of which I'm unaware but it's difficult to understand what that could be.

This same code works fine on Android and UWP.

```
private async void ShareButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(BindingContext is PhotoViewModel photoViewModel))
    {
        return;
    }

    // in UI context

    var name = photoViewModel.Name ?? "temp.jpg";
    var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, name);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(photoViewModel.Data, 0, photoViewModel.Data.Length);
    }

    // not in UI context!

    // calling this causes SIGABRT: UIKit Consistency error
    await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest(new ShareFile(file)));
}
```

Comment: Check the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` before the `await`. Xamarin should be setting that before starting the event handler so that the `await` resumes on the UI context.

Comment: @StephenCleary When you say check the value I'm not sure what I'm looking for.  I did try calling MainThread.IsMainThread (a Xamarin Essentials thing that seems to wrap NSThread on iOS), which is true before and false after.  The current context is not null in either case but I don't know what to look for beyond that.  Thanks.

Comment: Check to see if it's `null`, and if not, what type it is.

Comment: Both before and after it is not null and of type UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext

Comment: You should follow up with the Xamarin team, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in mono

https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/16759

Answer (score 2):

> calling this causes SIGABRT: UIKit Consistency error

```
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest(new ShareFile(file)));
```

Although there is no problem in Android and UWP, it may not be compatible with such writing in iOS. Above line code needs UI thread to invoke , however it is in `async` method `ShareButton_OnClicked`. Maybe need to invoke it from Main thread specially, have a try with the follow code to invoke it.

```
await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
{
    // inkoke your code .
    Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest(new ShareFile(file)));
});
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using but I don't understand why the context would not be set correctly in iOS.  In short, why is this necessary and how do I know this won't suddenly start happening in other handlers?

Comment: @Jeff I have checked in my project with [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#files) , there is no problem . I want to know whether your projecr using the latest version of VS(16.3.10) / Forms(4.3.0.991221) and Essentials (1.3.1).

Comment: I'm starting to think this is simply some sort of weird Xamarin bug